# detach/re-attach volume

Tags: mount, lvm

Tring to extend volume by doing the followings:

1. umount /dev/vdc
2. detach volume
3. edit volume (increase size)
4. attach volume

After re-attached the volume, it got assigned to /dev/vdd.

```
root@test-volume:/# lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda               252:0    0   20G  0 disk
├─vda1            252:1    0 19.9G  0 part /
├─vda14           252:14   0    4M  0 part
└─vda15           252:15   0  106M  0 part /boot/efi
vdb               252:16   0   64M  0 disk
vdd               252:48   0   15G  0 disk
└─vg_data-lv_data 253:0    0   15G  0 lvm
```

What should I do to remove /dev/vdc after detach so that the volume can be reattach to /dev/vdc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother about what device name a partition is assigned to. It is normal that the device name can, as you see, change. Consequently, it is not a reliable identifier of the partition or disk. Refer to the partition by UUID instead, and consider it very normal that a partition does not necessarily get the same device name.